# Using 3 Images instead of 1 in jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I really like this **jQuery Slider**: http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/

However, instead of 1 image per "slide", I'd like to have 3 smaller images.

Is this possible?

Any pointers at all with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Make your own, its not difficult - here's the source for the one you've linked to https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/master/source/slides.js you can get some help from that.

Comment: Example where I've tried to add 3 separate images to 1 slide: http://jsfiddle.net/uZDuK/

Comment: Thanks for the link, Thomas, but I'm really unsure where to begin. There's no mention of adding multiple images per slide in the source. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Thomas Clayson meant was that you could add some custom code to the plugin to create the same functionality

Anway the question is, do you realy need this specific plugin? There are a lot more plugins that do have similar functionality. For example the [InfiniteCarousel](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/12/30/huge-updates-to-jquery-infinite-carousel-version-2-released/). Have a look at [this example](http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/infinitecarousel2/demo/d3.html) that shows you 3 images at the time.

Comment: Thanks, Manuel. Infinite looks good. I've also found this: http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/app/webroot/assets/javascript/jquery/carousel/demo/ The only bit missing is a caption and the 'buttons' instead of numeric nav.